# Tomcat server on ubuntu is shutting down automatically when I am trying to run any project deployed in tomcat

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ubuntu

Error found in logs/localhost_access_log.xxxx.txt is "GET /testtom HTTP/1.1" 302

Issue found in logs/catalina.xxxx.log is

INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib

Comment: That's not an error (that's why is says `INFO`), and is not the issue. Please define what you mean by _shutting down automatically_.

Comment: As I try to access any link of any deployed project the tomcat server is stopped. I tried to see whether the tomcat is still running with command netstat -lnp | grep 8080 from the terminal and found that tomcat is not running anymore. The firefox browser says "The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments."

Comment: And you are certain that it is running previously - and accessible? Have you looked at Tomcat's STDOUT - usually catalina.out.

Comment: Yes it was running previously. I tried accessing the deployed projects from manager apps of tomcat. The catalina.out says "INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib"

Comment: You said that was the catalina.log, what does the catalina.out say?

Comment: catalina.out also said the same thing. I just fount one more stuff in catalina.out. It says "INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time."